# How do I make dynamic hyperlinks based on query string value?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, asp-classic

I would like to start off saying that I'm very new to programming. I am developing a site (`www.example.com`) that has multiple hyperlinks.

When a user visits my site I want all the links to be defaulted to the back office of another site (`www.tvcmatrix.com/mhammonds`) I use. How do I set the links to redirect to the query string value based on inputted text from a form that is on my site (`www.example.com`)?

In other words, if the url reads `www.example.com/?user=abelliard`, how do I make all the links on the site change to "www.tvcmatrix.com/abelliard"? If no query string is present, then I would like for the links to be `www.tvcmatrix.com/mhammonds`.

Here is a file on my site for the form called "form.asp"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="viral.asp" method="get" name="input" target="_self">
            Your TVC Matrix Associate ID: <input type="text" name="user" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the "viral.asp" file in the "form.asp" file.

```js
<%@ language="javascript"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <%
        var id = Request.QueryString("user");                    
        Response.Write("Your URL is: www.mca.com/?user=" + id)
    %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use an if statement and set the value to mhammonds if the querystring  is empty ("")

```
<%
Dim id = Request.QueryString("user")
Dim url = id                 
If id = ""  Then
  url = "mhammonds"
End If
 'Every URL in your site reads    
Response.Write "www.tvcmatrix.com/" & id 

%>
```

`

Comment: I inputted this, but it didn't work for me. I did however change the Dim to var, lower cased the "I's" in if, and changed the & to + being that I am using javascript and not vbscript. I wasn't exactly sure where to put it either so I tried multiple places. None worked for me. @schar

Comment: After `<html>`, add `<head>` and put in `<base href="` then your `<% .. %>` code, then `"></head>`.